# How to test if a SQL Server 2008 database can serve 200 concurent users

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, load-testing

I have a SQL Server 2008 database in 3NF.

I must check if the db can support many concurent users.

Which is the best method ?

Is there any free tool to do this ?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLQueryStress - http://www.datamanipulation.net/SQLQueryStress/documentation/documentation.asp

and

SQLStress - http://www.sqlstress.com/Overview.aspx

Both look like a good fit for what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks !

Yes, I am looking for this kind of tools.

Answer (score 1):

The database design and the queries you run against it are *vital;* no generic answer can be reliable.

I recommend you start with the MS SQL community's benchmark tools.

Comment: Thanks.

Yes, the design and queries are vital.

What do you think about this tool ?
http://www.seapine.com/qawizard.html

Comment: Sorry, don't know that one. -shrug-

Answer (score 0):

Since uses are hopefully not accessing the database directly you must have some front end, that is where I would perform my load test. You can use TFS to do load tests as well as [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have created some kind of web front end that queries your database, then the excellent open source tool [Sahi](http://sahi.co.in/w/) would really help you out.  The test toolkit allows you to simulate multiple users using your website - and therefore your database.